# How can i add image zoom for magento luma theme

Tags: magento-2.1

How to add image zoom function in magento luma theme. when i add image zoom extension getting extension errors.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File path for luma theme :

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml
```

You need to change below option for enable image zoom

```
<var name="gallery">
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
</var>

<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="enabled">true</var>
</var>
```

clean cache and check.